# How to find other equations of lagrange for the Initial Value Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the solution of the Initial Value Problem

$(x-y)\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+(y-x-u)\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=u$

where $u(x,0)=1$ .

**My try**:

$\dfrac{dx}{x-y}=\dfrac{dy}{y-x-u}=\dfrac{du}{u}$

Now $\dfrac{dx+dy}{-u}=\dfrac{du}{u}\implies x+y+u=c_1$

But I am not getting any other conditions to work on.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use multipliers $1,-1,1$ and then equate to the third term.

**Edit:** Using above you will get, $$\frac{dx-dy+du}{2(x-y+u)}=\frac{du}{u}$$ Now solve, and you will get $\frac{x-y+u}{u^2}=c_2$. Then combine with the one you have already found and use the initial condition.

Comment: I did not get that

Comment: see the edit @learnmore

Comment: Yes I found the answer to be $u^2(x+y+u)+(x-y+u)=0$;;; Thank you very much

Comment: Glad t hear that and all the best for your exam.

Comment: Which exam ?@kushal

Comment: I thought u r going to appear in NET. never mind.

Comment: Oh yes I have heard about it.I will have to appear one day .Did you appear for the exam ;what was the outcome ?is it very difficult ;all my seniors say so;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41290/discussion-between-kushal-bhuyan-and-learnmore).

Comment: What do you do now?just asking for curiosity ;ignore if you mind it